# Sort a (nested) list of strings on frequency of occurrence

Tags: python

So I got a list which looks like this:

```
['Marie', 'Lucas', 'Patsy', 'Julie', 'Peter', 'Emma', 'Kevin', 'Tobias', 'Suzy', ['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Marie'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Patsy', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Emma'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Kevin', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Emma', 'Peter'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Peter'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Julie', 'Peter'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias'], ['Tobias', 'Suzy']]
```

I want to sort the list based on highest occurrences to lowest. I used `print((Counter(str(netwerk)).most_common()))` which returned instead:

```
[("'", 82), (',', 40), (' ', 40), ('a', 25), ('e', 23), ('[', 17), (']', 17), ('u', 15), ('s', 15), ('m', 14), ('i', 12), ('r', 10), ('P', 10), ('t', 10), ('L', 9), ('c', 9), ('E', 7), ('y', 6), ('M', 3), ('J', 3), ('l', 3), ('K', 3), ('v', 3), ('n', 3), ('T', 3), ('o', 3), ('b', 3), ('S', 3), ('z', 3)]
```

The occurrences of a single char, I have no clue why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

My expected result would be:

```
Lucas – Emma – Peter – Julie – Kevin – Marie – Patsy – Suzy – Tobias
```

Comment: Do sublists have any kind of importance here? If not, we should flatten the list before working on it.

Comment: You're sorting a single string which breaks down to a list of chars when iterating. It's never going to work with the `str()`. As @Guimoute said, flattening the list will make it easier. Alternatively you'll have to manually loop through it and store in a separate counter.

Comment: You don't have a list, you have a *string* that looks like a list. There is no other explanation for how `'` and `]` and `[` end up being in your result.

Comment: Flattening the list is not an option as the subelements of one bracket indicate a relationship between both.

Comment: Ok but does this relationship affect the counter? Please add the expected output. We don't know if you want to sort single names by frequency of occurence (including those in sublists), or single+couple names.

Comment: Yes so for instance Marie and Peter occur three times. Added expected result in the post.

Comment: Do you need to consider _n_ levels of nested lists or can we assume to have one "sublevel" only? In addition, your expected result seems to contain only first-level names. Is that correct?

Comment: No, just the total occurrences in the list, so if there's an occurrence in a sublist it counts as one.

Comment: @LLScheme So we can work on a flattened list ;-)

Comment: @Guimote, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Counter` directly because there are some `list` mixed in with string, therefore flatten those first:

```
data = ['Marie', 'Lucas', 'Patsy', 'Julie', 'Peter', 'Emma', 'Kevin', 'Tobias', 'Suzy', ['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Marie'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Patsy', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Emma'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Kevin', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Emma', 'Peter'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Peter'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Julie', 'Peter'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias'], ['Tobias', 'Suzy']]
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for d in data:
    if isinstance(d,str):
        c[d] += 1
    elif isinstance(d,list):
        for n in d:
            c[n] += 1
c.most_common()
```

Output:

```
[('Lucas', 9),
 ('Peter', 7),
 ('Emma', 7),
 ('Tobias', 3),
 ('Patsy', 3),
 ('Marie', 3),
 ('Suzy', 3),
 ('Kevin', 3),
 ('Julie', 3)]
```